# PHP json_encode a debug_backtrace() with resource types

Tags: php, resources, json, backtrace

Currently, I have a logger which logs errors together with a backtrace.
The logger serializes the backtrace to JSON via `json_encode()`.

Let's look at some hypothetical code...

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);                          // show all errors
    function test($b){
        echo json_encode(debug_backtrace());      // take a backtrace snapshot
    }
    $c = imagecreate(50,50);                      // create a resource...
    test($c);                                     // ...and pass to function
?>
```

If you [run the code above](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ch6gVw), we will see something like:

> **Warning:** json_encode() [function.json-encode]: **type is unsupported, encoded as null** in /code/ch6gVw on line 5
>   [{"file":"/code/ch6gVw","line":8,"function":"test","args":[null]}]

We can notice two things going on here:

1. The logger itself is causing a warning! Bad bad bad!
2. The logged data tells us we passed a null to the function?!?!

---

**So, my proposed solution is something like:**

```
foreach($trace as $i=>$v)
    if(is_resource($v))
        $trace[$i] = (string)$v.' ('.get_resource_type($v).')';
```

The result would look like `Resource id #1 (gd)`

---

**This, however, may cause some grave issues.**

1. We need to somehow track which arrays we looped through so as to avoid ending up in infinite loops with arrays referencing themselves (`$GLOBALS` tend to cause this mess).
2. We would also have to convert resources of object properties, but objects, unlike arrays, are not a copy of the original thing, hence changing the property changes the live object. On the other hand, how safe is it to `clone()` the object?
3. Won't such a loop severely slow down the server (backtraces tend to be large, no)?

Comment: potential issue with json for encoding a PHP backtrace: json does not allow for binary data.

Comment: Instead if JSON, what about simply `var_export(..., true)`?

Comment: @Jacco - Doesn't `json_encode()` allow for bson (or am I dreaming this)?

@deceze - It converts resource to null as well: http://codepad.viper-7.com/46uo3Q

Comment: `serialize()`, on the other hand, converts them to a `0 (int)` (!)

Comment: bson isn't json, they just surfed along on the name.

Comment: @Jacco Still, doesn't json encode such data correctly (http://codepad.viper-7.com/e8W58w)?

Comment: On the other hand, the kind of encoding is mostly irrelevant. Fact remains that a PHP resource cannot be serialized/encoded nicely. I only need to fix this specific issue, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the following function:

```
function clean_trace($branch){
    if(is_object($branch)){
        // object
        $props = array();
        $branch = clone($branch); // doesn't clone cause some issues?
        foreach($props as $k=>$v)
            $branch->$k = clean_trace($v);
    }elseif(is_array($branch)){
        // array
        foreach($branch as $k=>$v)
            $branch[$k] = clean_trace($v);
    }elseif(is_resource($branch)){
        // resource
        $branch = (string)$branch.' ('.get_resource_type($branch).')';
    }elseif(is_string($branch)){
        // string (ensure it is UTF-8, see: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47130)
        $branch = utf8_encode($branch);
    }
    // other (hopefully serializable) stuff
    return $branch;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aKoukw). However, **I'm not convinced**:

- It is quite slow (iterating over lots of data)
- It is quite memory intensive (data needs to be copied to not mess the original)
- It is not safe in case where arrays/objects reference themselves

  - Example: `$a = array();  $a['ref'] = &$a;` (PHP does this to some internal variables)
- I'm concerned that cloning objects may have some serious side-effects (consider the magic method `__clone()`, an invitation to wreck havoc).

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to store the backtrace as a data structure that can be used to pretty-print the results later on?

If that isn't needed I'd just store `$result = print_r(debug_backtrace(), true)` and be done with it.

If not my first shot would be something like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
function test($b){
    echo json_encode(clean(debug_backtrace()));
}   
$c = fopen("/tmp/foo", "w");
test($c);


function clean($trace) {
    array_walk_recursive($trace, function(&$element) {
        if(is_object(&$element)) {
            // work around unrealizable elements and preserve typing
            $element = array(get_class($element), (object)$element); 
        } else if(is_resource($element)) {
            $element = get_resource_type($element) . '#'  .(int)$element;
        }   
    }); 
    return $trace;
}
```

It's just a rough sketch but I'm not aware of any project that stores backtracks for later inspection in a non textual or already processed format and looking around the mature frameworks didn't bring anything up

Comment: Later on, I'm "inspecting" the backtrace rather than just printing it. Eventually, I'll be writing some code to get statistics about the trace, so it's hard to just store the print_r-ed content. I think.

Comment: Why you try cast an **object** to **object** ?